# laravel cant find method in live server

Tags: php, laravel

i'm facing a weird error in my machine locally everything is working properly while when i throw the project in server live i have this problem BadMethodCallException which says cant find the method but the method actually it exist, i tried everything php artisan key:generate, composer dump-autoload, php artisan cache:config but with no success.

my route:

```
Route::get('/forgotpassword',[
    'as'    =>  "forgotpassword",
    'uses'  =>  "admin@forgotpassword"
]);
```

controller:

```
//Forgot Password
public function forgotpassword()
{
    return view('page.forgotpassword');
}
```

And error i'm getting:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\admin::forgotpassword does not exist.
```

Comment: please post your namespace

Comment: Please put your controller code

Comment: admin controller: 

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class admin extends Controller
{
   
    //Login Admin
    public function login()
    {
        return view('page.login');
    }
    //Forgot Password
    public function forgotpassword()
    {
        return view('page.forgotpassword');
    }

only home route works which is: login()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Route::get('/forgotpassword',[
    'as'    =>  "forgotpassword",
    'uses'  =>  "Admin@forgotpassword"
]);
```

> Remember: All class name is case-sensitive. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/) corrected this automatically.

Comment: when i make 'uses'  =>  "Admin@forgotpassword" 

"Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin does not exist"

Comment: Then add your full controller's code in question's description. @spyrox

Answer (score 0):

usually this happens when you develop in windows but host it on Linux.

In Linux we have to also take care of the case sensitivity.

make sure your class name is same as you are referencing in your routes.

e.g

```
Route::get('/forgotpassword',[
    'as'    =>  "forgotpassword",
    'uses'  =>  "admin@forgotpassword"
]);
```

for the above given route you must have a controller name with lower case.

e.g

```
class admin extends Controller {}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i have it like that class admin extends Controller but i can't understand how can't find the method while the post method it works if i try to login it goes in controller and it gives me response so post request is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers; 

 use App\Http\Controllers;

 class Admin extends Controller { 

 }
```

**Route**

```
    Route::get('/forgotpassword',[
    'as'    =>  "forgotpassword",
    'uses'  =>  "Admin@forgotpassword"
]);
```